# Selected row does't update in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datatable bound to my datagridview. One of the columns is a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn.

By clicking on a button you should change all checkboxes in the column to true.

```
private void btnPublishAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < this.dgrView.RowCount; j++)
  {
    this.dgrView[7, j].Value = true;
  }

  this.dgrView.EndEdit();
}
```

When I press the button everything seems ok(all checkboxes are true), but when I press update everything is updated except the row that was selected during btnPublishAll_Click.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: would you post the code of the update method ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem!

I needed to add

```
this.BindingContext[this.dgrView.DataSource].EndCurrentEdit();
```

instead of

```
this.dgrView.EndEdit();
```